# How to extract data from complex json with Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to extract data from this json file in format like this:

```
    [{'from': '2019-11-22T12:45:00-05:00',
  'to': '2019-11-22T12:50:00-05:00',
  'value': [{'value': 0, 'label': 'fw'}, {'value': 0, 'label': 'bw'}]},
 {'from': '2019-11-22T12:50:00-05:00',
  'to': '2019-11-22T12:55:00-05:00',
  'value': [{'value': 0, 'label': 'fw'}, {'value': 1, 'label': 'bw'}]},
 {'from': '2019-11-22T12:55:00-05:00',
  'to': '2019-11-22T13:00:00-05:00',
  'value': [{'value': 0, 'label': 'fw'}, {'value': 0, 'label': 'bw'}]}]
```

The goal is to  get the columns "from", "to", "value" and label"
So I should have 6 row of data, 2 row  for each instance of time, something like this:
[image]

I have tried using

pd.DataFrame function from pandas and i get output like this:

[image]

Any suggestion how do i go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could `explode` the `value` column, and then extract the actual `label` and `value` fields. But IMHO it is simpler and faster to pre-process `data`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[d['from'], d['to'], d1['value'], d1['label']]
                    for d in data for d1 in d['value']],
                   columns=['from', 'to', 'value', 'label'])
```